# Delete using a different delimiter with Sed

Tags: sed

Fairly certain I am missing something obvious!

```
$ cat test.txt
  00 30 * * * /opt/timebomb.sh >> timebomb.log
  01 30 * * * /opt/reincarnate.sh >> reincarnation.log
$ sed ':timebomb:d' test.txt
  00 30 * * * /opt/timebomb.sh >> timebomb.log
  01 30 * * * /opt/reincarnate.sh >> reincarnation.log
```

whereas

```
$ sed '/timebomb/d' test.txt
  01 30 * * * /opt/reincarnate.sh >> reincarnation.log
```

Why is it the case? Aren't a different set of delimiters supported for the `d` command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use slashes in sed replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The delimiters `//` that you're using are not for the `d` command, they're for the addressing. I think you're comparing them to the slashes in the `s///` command... However although both relate to regular expressions, they are different contexts.

The address (which appears **before** the command) filters which lines the command is applied to... The options (which appear **after** the command) are used to control the replacement applied.

If you want to use different delimiters for a regular expression in the address, you need to start the address with a backslash:

```
$ sed '\:timebomb:d' test.txt
  01 30 * * * /opt/reincarnate.sh >> reincarnation.log
```

(To understand the difference between the address and the options, consider the output of the command:

```
$ sed '/timebomb/s/log/txt/' test.txt
```

The address chooses only the line(s) containing the regular expression `timebomb`, but the options tell the `s` command to replace the regular expression `log` with `txt`.)

Comment: Many thanks for mentioning the option to start with a backslash!

Answer (score 1):

The colon preceeds a label in sed, so your sed program looks like a couple of labels with nothing happening. The parser can see colons as delimiters if preceded by the s command, so that's a special case.

Answer (score 0):

use gawk

```
gawk '!/timebomb/' file > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the shell, no need external tools

```
while read -r line
do 
    case "$line" in
        *timebomb* ) continue;;
        *) echo "$line";;
    esac        
done <"file"
```