# Using different delimiters in sed commands and range addresses

Tags: sed

I am using sed in a shell script to edit filesystem path names. Suppose I want to replace

```
/foo/bar
```

with

```
/baz/qux
```

However, sed's `s///` command uses the forward slash `/` as the delimiter. If I do that, I see an error message emitted, like:

```
▶ sed 's//foo/bar//baz/qux//' FILE
sed: 1: "s//foo/bar//baz/qux//": bad flag in substitute command: 'b'
```

Similarly, sometimes I want to select line ranges, such as the lines between a pattern `foo/bar` and `baz/qux`. Again, I can't do this:

```
▶ sed '/foo/bar/,/baz/qux/d' FILE
sed: 1: "/foo/bar/,/baz/qux/d": undefined label 'ar/,/baz/qux/d'
```

What can I do?

Comment: `sed statement <<< cat`

Comment: @geirha not sure what you mean here.

Comment: Try `sed 'sahanag' <<< "haha"`. In your aaa's example it fails only because the regex is blank and your either branching to an unlabeled a location, and the g command needs to be segregated with a semicolon - or - you are branching to an unlabeled ag location. You can also use unprintable characters to delimit such as `SOH $'\001'`. You can see an working example here: https://github.com/AdamDanischewski/gen-uniq-id/blob/master/gen_uniq_id.bsh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a variable containing slashes to sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787536/how-to-pass-a-variable-containing-slashes-to-sed)

Comment: But then on the other hand the answer here is rather spare. Perhaps they should be merged.

Comment: @tripleee yeah, that could work. Just showing my preference for this one because it has a better SEO (33K visits in 5y, while the other 22K in 10y)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can use an alternative regex delimiter as a search pattern by backslashing it:

```
sed '\,some/path,d'
```

And just use it as is for the `s` command:

```
sed 's,some/path,other/path,'
```

You probably want to protect other metacharacters, though; this is a good place to  use Perl and `quotemeta`, or equivalents in other scripting languages.

From `man sed`:

> `/regexp/`
>   Match lines matching the regular expression *`regexp`*.
>
> `\cregexpc`
>   Match lines matching the regular expression *`regexp`*. The `c` may be any character other than backslash or newline.
>
> `s/regular expression/replacement/flags`
>   Substitute the replacement string for the first instance of the regular expression in the pattern space.  Any character other than backslash or newline can be used instead of a slash to delimit the RE and the replacement.  Within the RE and the replacement, the RE delimiter itself can be used as a literal character if it is preceded by a backslash.

Comment: And to use a different delimiter for a start and ending search pattern a la `/foo/,/bar/`, use `sed '\=some/path=,\=other/path='`. Notice you have to repeat the escape character \ at the beginning of the 2nd search pattern. Obvious if you think about it, but it puzzled me a moment.

Answer (score 47):

Perhaps the closest to a standard, the POSIX/IEEE Open Group Base Specification [says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/sed.html):

> **[2addr] s/BRE/replacement/flags**
>
> Substitute the replacement string for instances of the BRE in the
>   pattern space. **Any character other than backslash or newline** can
>   be used instead of a slash to delimit the BRE and the replacement.
>   Within the BRE and the replacement, the BRE delimiter itself can be
>   used as a literal character if it is preceded by a backslash."

Answer (score -1):

When there is a slash `/` in the original string or the replacement string, we need to escape it using `\`.

```bash
sed 's/\/foo\/bar/\/baz\/qux/' file
```

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 (`sed` 4.2.2).