# SED - stripping certain tags from XML file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, sed

I have some xml files littered with tags like this:

```
<?xm-insertion_mark_start author="some_author" time="20050602T125956-0500"?>
```

How would I strip such inserts? I've tried this to avail:

```
sed -e 's/<\?xm.*?\?>//g' in.xml > out.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of substitute (s) use delete (d) command of sed:

Also use `sed -i` (inline) like this:

```
sed -i.bak '/<?xm.*?>/d' in.xml
```

**Using grep:**

```
grep -v '<\?xm.*\?>' in.xml > out.xml
```

*Caution: shell utilities are not always the best tools for parsing & editing  XML data.*

Comment: @Tomalak: I didn't use non-greedy quantifier in my sed command. It is escaped `\?` that matched literal `?`.

Comment: Yeah that's why I removed my comment. In any case, your expression is dangerous and should not be used. It can and will destroy the XML file (if it contains multiple processing instructions) due to the greedy `.*`.

Comment: @Tomalak: For that matter any sed command can break the XML, what if above `<?xm...?>` line has linefeed, newline characters?

Comment: Hm... you are right. The expression in my answer would deal with them, you'd have to set the line separator to something other than `\n` to make it work. Since XML cannot legally contain, say `\0x8`, you could use that as a line separator and deal with the file as one single line. (I don't know if that's easily possible though - [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6927998/18771) suggests to pipe through `tr` to replace `\n` with something `sed` does not recognize)

Comment: `?` is not a metacharacter for `sed`. Don't escape it to match literally.

Answer (score 1):

sed does not have reluctant ("non-greedy") quantifiers. Try this:

```
sed '/<?xm\([^?][^>]\)\+?>/d' in.xml > out.xml
```

---

EDIT: Of course you could use XSLT to safely remove the processing instruction (PI) from the XML.

This removes all PIs named `xm-insertion_mark_start` but leaves all remaining XML untouched.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('xm-insertion_mark_start')" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Use

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()" />
```

if you want to remove *all* PIs regardless of their name.

You can use `xsltproc(1)` to apply the transformation to your XML on the command line.

Comment: It's incorrect. In `sed` the `?` is not a metacharacter. you have to leave it unescaped to match it literally. Parentheses are metacharacters so you need to escape them and the same for `+`.

Comment: Not quite. Either `)`, `(` and `+` must be escaped to apply its special meaning. Maybe I said it wrong in my previous comment, sorry. Without escaping them they match literal, it's the same that `?`. As alternation, using `--regex-extended` lets you to use `?`, `+`, `(` and `)` without escaping, like most of other languages regex flavours (and your first version had worked with it).

Comment: In a way sed's regexes work like vim's. I keep forgetting that. Now it should be all-right.

Comment: Yes. I'ts very similar as the *magic* version. All escaped unless `*`, zero-width assertions and a few more.

Comment: I don't do a lot with sed, though I do a lot with regexes and with vim, too - maybe now I get sed answers right more often.