# sed, foward slash in quotes

Tags: bash, sed, escaping, quotes

I'm trying to do something in `bash` with `sed` that is proving to be extremely difficult.

I have a `bash` script that takes as its first argument a date.

The code want to change a line in a text file to include the passed date.  Here's the code

```
#!/bin/bash

cq_fname="%let outputfile="/user/cq_"$1".csv";"

sed "29s/.*/\"$ct_fname\"/" file1.sas > file2.sas
```

This script fails on the third line, I get something about a garbled command.  Does anybody know a clever way to get this to work? How can I get a forward slash in quotes in `sed`?

Comment: What's the result of all that parameter expansion *supposed* to look like?

Comment: clarification: Basically, I'm trying to replace line 29 of file1.sas with:
%let outputfile="/user/cq_20060104.csv";

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use slashes in sed replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use any character in place of the `/`, so just pick one that is not in `$ct_fname`:

```
sed "29s|.*|\"$ct_fname\"|" file1.sas > file2.sas
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax highlighting here should be a good indicator of what your problem is -- you've got several strings smashed together with content that isn't in the strings. Try replacing this:

```
cq_fname="%let outputfile="/user/cq_"$1".csv";"
```

with this:

```
cq_fname="%let outputfile=\"/user/cq_$1.csv\";"
```

I escaped the `"` inside the string with `\` characters and removed the `"` characters that felt like they probably don't exist in the filename.

[Alok suggests using a different character for the replacement command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11147402/377270) -- that's necessary.

Also, you need to use the same variable name in both the assignment *and* the string. (D'oh!)

The final script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cq_fname="%let outputfile=\"/user/cq_$1.csv\";"
sed "29s|.*|$cq_fname|" file1.sas > file2.sas
```

I found the mis-matched variable names by adding `set -x` to the top of the script; it showed the execution output of the script along the way.

Broken:

```
$ ./replace 
+ cq_fname='%let outputfile="/user/cq_.csv";'
+ sed '29s|.*||' file1.sas
```

Fixed:

```
$ ./replace 
+ cq_fname='%let outputfile="/user/cq_.csv";'
+ sed '29s|.*|%let outputfile="/user/cq_.csv";|' file1.sas
```

`set -x` is a superb little debugging tool, when you need it.

Comment: Hrn. Could you include the sample input, command, and output you'd like?

Comment: clarification added to original question

Comment: Thanks, with another re-poke I found that the variable name was incorrect. Fixing that, using Alok's `s|||` trick, and fixing the quoting, you've finally got the whole thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

On every other set of quotes, use ' (single quote) instead of " (double quote).

Comment: Single-quotes may not work in the `.sas` file format -- and the `$1` needs to be interpreted by the shell, so I don't think replacing the _outer_ quotes with `'` will work either.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
cq_fname='%let outputfile="/user/cq_.csv";'
sed '29c\'"$cq_fname" file1.sas > file2.sas
```