# Escape a path for sed search pattern

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sed, foward slash in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147323/sed-foward-slash-in-quotes)

In my bash script I have a path string, which I should use in `sed` pattern.

```
SRC_PATH="$PWD"
sed "s/<SRC_PATH>/$SRC_PATH/g" template.sh > replaced.sh
```

How can I escape the `$SRC_PATH` string so it would be safely accepted by sed as a literal replacement?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147323/sed-foward-slash-in-quotes/11147402

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need not escape it. Just use other delimiter:

```
sed "s@<SRC_PATH>@$SRC_PATH@g" template.sh > replaced.sh
```

But you must be sure that SRC_PATH contains no `@` (or other symbol if you choose it).

Comment: for gnu sed, see also https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses

Answer (score 0):

Use `s%$OLDPATH%$NEWPATH%`.  You can choose your delimiter.  If `%` is too dangerous, consider <kbd>Control-A</kbd> instead.