# How to match double quotes using sed

Tags: unix, sed, tcsh

How can I make sed use double quotes (`"`) as a match?

I try to replace `"source/design` to `"source/design_new` only without changing the second coding.

Input:

```
"source/design",  
"include/source/design",
```

Expect Output:

```
"source/design_new",    #only this line renaming  
"include/source/design"
```

I tried with command:

```
sed "s/\"source\/design/\"source\/design_new/g"
```

but it is complaining with an `unmatched "` error. Is there any way to use double quotes in `sed`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed, foward slash in quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147323/sed-foward-slash-in-quotes)

Answer (score 4):

Basically, `sed` takes whatever follows the `s` as the separator (except newline or backslash). So you can use some any other character - let's say `;` - as a separator instead of `/`.

**Example:**

```
sed 's;"source/design;"source/design_new;g' input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use single quotes around the command instead of double quotes. This way you do not have to worry about how to handle them:

```
sed 's~"source/design~"source/design_new~g' file
    ^                                     ^
```

With your given input this command returns:

```
"source/design_new",  
"include/source/design",
```

Also note you can avoid escaping every `/` by using another separator in `sed` (I used `~`, although it could also be `|` or another one).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to tcsh. You can't include double quotes in doublequotes. End the double quotes and backslash the double quote:

```
sed "s/"\""source\/design/"\""source\/design_new/g"
```

Or, more readable (using a different separator to avoid the need to backslash slashes, and using no quotes as they're not needed for letters, slashes and underscores:

```
sed s=\"source/design=\"source/design_new=g
```