# find and replace using sed in unix

Tags: unix, sed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use slashes in sed replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace)

I need to find the following string `/a/b/c` and replace it with `/r/s/t`

It is a string and not a folder

`/sam/pam/nancy`   -->  `/tim/cook/iphone`

I am in the directory and just need to update multiple files having this line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sed` to change the files in-place. For example:

```
sed -i 's|/a/b/c|/r/s/t|g' *.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pi -e 's/\/a\/b\/c/\/r\/s\/t/g' file_name
```