# Trying to escape a / for sed on ubuntu

Tags: sed

I am trying to use sed to replace a path in a file.

```
sudo sed 's/a/b/g' -i /tmp/test
```

However the variable is

```
a = /var/lib and 
b = /data/lib
```

How do I escape the slash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use slashes in sed replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The character just after the `s` command doesn't need to be a `/`. When working with paths, I use `:`, as in:

```
sudo sed 's:a:b:g' -i /tmp/test
```

Comment: very often URLs contain `:` as well. So using `#` instead is more ultimate solution, as @Chris Seymour replied

Comment: @kiedysktos - URLs may also contain `#`.

Comment: that's true. Anyway the point is you need to pick a character that is not in the URL

Answer (score 2):

You can change sed's delimiter for instance use `#` instead:

```
$ sed 's#/var/lib#data/lib#g'
/var/lib   
data/lib
```

Answer (score 2):

this should work

```
sed  -i "s@$a@$b@g" /tmp/test
```

two things you need to take care about:

1) if you want to use variables in your sed line, use **double quotes**

2) delimiter could be other than "`/`", e.g. `@, #, : ...`

Answer (score 0):

In sed(1), as in vi(1), the '/' is just the customary separator. It can be escaped with `\`, leading to "leaning toothpick syndrome" when munging path names:

`sed -e 's/\/var\/lib/data\/lib/' ...`

You can use another non-word character, e.g. ';':

`sed -e 's;/var/lib;data/lib; ...`