# Substitution contains sed delimiter and extended regex features

Tags: sed

I am trying to use sed to match and replace a string of the following nature `somedate:"12/12/2012"` using `sed 's/somedate:"[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}"//g'`

This expression does not match anything in the string `something and somedate:"12/12/2012" and something else`

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using different delimiters in sed commands and range addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/using-different-delimiters-in-sed-commands-and-range-addresses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few points:

- You use `/` as the delimiter for `sed` but the substitution contains `/` so choose a different delimiter such as `|` or escape the `/` in the substitution with `\`. Any delimiter can used with `sed`.
- The quantifier `{n}` is part of the extended regexp class so use the `-r` option (or `-E` for BSD derivatives of `sed`) or again escape the extended features like `\{2\}`.
- The `g` flag may or may not be needed depending if you have multiple matches on a single line. It doesn't make a difference for your given example but it's worth pointing out.
- You probably want `{1,2}` for the days and months *i.e* `1/1/2012`.

I would do:

```bsh
$ sed -r 's|somedate:"[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}"||' file
something and  and something else
```

Alternatively by escaping everything:

```bsh
$ sed 's/somedate:"[0-9]\{1,2\}\/[0-9]\{1,2\}\/[0-9]\{4\}"//' file
something and  and something else
```

Comment: I did not know that one could use any delimiter with sed --so Thanks for that pointer.  However, neither of these expressions match 'somedate:' in the example string.

Comment: @cer_albastru actually they both do see http://ideone.com/xcYYqD you must be doing something different.

Comment: I am using cygwin and here is what I tried:  echo 'something and somedate:"10/3/2011" and anotherdate:"1/31/2012" and (one or two )' | sed -r 's|somedate:"[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}"||' --any ideas?

Comment: Haha look at the date in that test string it's only one digit, not two `:]` You want `sed -r 's|somedate:"[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}"||'`.