# Search and Replace SED Linux

Tags: linux, sed

I need to convert my all url relative path

```
https://www.example.com/image/abc.gif   to  /image/abc.gif
```

i tried this command but not worked for `https:\\` section  . How can i use `https\\` in this command .

```
   grep -rl "http://www.example.com" /root/ | xargs sed -i 's/http://www.example.com//g'
```

Comment: When I use `/` in my search portion for `sed`, i like to make my `/` delimiter something else for readability: `sed -i 's?some\/path\/here?new\/path\/here?g`   Also, remember to escape your slashes in your search and replace strings ie. `//` becomes `\/\/`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use slashes in sed replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace)

Comment: Is domain always the same trough the file? eg: `www.example.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do the job:

```
echo "https://www.example.com/image/abc.gif" | sed 's/https:\/\/www\.example\.com//g'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
/image/abc.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, the -r indicates extended regexes. The ? says 0 or 1 occurrence of 's'.

```
echo "http://www.example.com/image/abc.gif" | sed -r 's/https?:\/\/www\.example\.com//g'
```