# How do I take the output of recursive grep and split it into an array like variable?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, sed, zsh

I'm trying to create a shell search and replace function to replace all occurrences of a string in a directory. The problem is how do I take the output of recursive grep and use it to find files to use for sed?

I've got the following pipeline `grep -R protal ./ | sed 's/:.*//g' | sed 's/\/\//\//g'`. It produces this output:

```
./settings.py
./settings.py
./settings.py
./urls.py
./wsgi.py
./wsgi.py
```

I want to take this and split it into an array or something so I can do (pseudo-code):

```
for [[ $file in $file_list ]]; do
   sed -i 's/$input_string/$replace_value/g' $file
done
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to parse a file list (which could be a problem when you have whitespaces or newlines in file names), I'd do the whole thing with `find` and its `-exec` filter:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q protal '{}' \; -exec sed -i "s/$input_string/$replace_value/" '{}' \;
```

The trick is that

- the `-exec` filter only passes if the command returns with exit status `0`,
- that `grep -q protal file.txt` returns with exit status `0` only if `file.txt` contains `protal`, and that
- the second `-exec` filter, since it is chained after the first, will only be attempted (and the associated command only executed) if the first filter passes.

This has the effect of running `sed -i "s/$input_string/$replace_value/"` for regular files under the current directory that contain `protal`.

Comment: This is the only sane answer.

Comment: Ok, so I like this answer, and it's certainly better than my original idea, however, I'm getting an error. Sed returns `sed: 1: "./file": invalid command code .` What's up with that?

Comment: Does one of the shell variables contain a slash? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace

Comment: Another wild guess: If you're using Mac OS X or a BSD, those come with BSD sed, which expects a filename extension for the backup file as parameter to `-i`. It would treat `s/.../.../` as the filename extension and the filename as sed code. I believe it allows an empty extension to avoid the generation of a backup file, so you could try `-exec sed -i '' "s/$input_string/$replace_string/" '{}' \;`; if that doesn't work, `-exec sed -i.bak "s/$input_string/$replace_string/" '{}' \; -exec rm '{}.bak' \;` will do the trick (if no `foo.bak` files that need to be preserved are in the directory tree).

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in $(grep -R protal ./ | sed 's/:.*//g' | sed 's/\/\//\//g'); do
#yourcode
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `xargs` :

```
grep -R protal ./ | sed 's/:.*//g' | sed 's/\/\//\//g' | xargs  sed -i 's/$input_string/$replace_value/g'
```