# sed not working correctly when using variables

Tags: shell

```
source=<!--jta-data-source>jdbc/FCBDataSource</jta-data-source-->

destination=<jta-data-source>jdbc/FCBDataSource</jta-data-source>


sed -i "s/$source/$destination/g" /home/rohan/R2.5LZN/UIReleasedArea/obp.ui.domain/persistence.xml
```

I am getting error `sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unknown option to s`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use slashes in sed replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace)

Comment: [Recommended reading](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/2088135)

Comment: Also shell variables don' t expand in single quotes so that command as written wouldn't give that error it would just fail to do what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what happens when the substitution occurs.  The command becomes:

```
sed -i 's/<!--jta-data-source>jdbc/FCBDataSource</jta-data-source-->/<jta-data-source>jdbc/FCBDataSource</jta-data-source>/g' some_filename
```

Then, `sed` sees `s/<!--jta-data-source>jdbc/FCBDataSource</j…` and thinks that you want to replace an occurrence of `<!--jta-data-source>jdbc` with the text `FCBDataSource<`, and the `s` command has an illegal `j` modifier (and other junk).

You need to pick a delimiter character that does not appear in either the pattern or the replacement text.  A `,` will do.

Answer (score 0):

```
destination='<!--jta-data-source>jdbc/FCBDataSource</jta-data-source-->'
source='<jta-data-source>jdbc/FCBDataSource</jta-data-source>'


sed -i "s,$source,$destination,g"     
/home/rohan/R2.5LZN/UIReleasedArea/obp.ui.domain/persistence.xml
```

The problem was with the variable

Quotes were required

Comment: Right solution, poor explanation.