# Using sed to replace string with dots like 2.1.3

Tags: macos, sed

On OSX,  I am trying to replace all occurrences of 2.7.10 in certain path in the following manner:

```
find . -type f  -path '*/*/dev/composer.json' \
-exec sed -i -e 's/2.7.10/dev-supported/7.x-2.7.10/g' {} \;`
```

but the above command fails with error `bad flag in substitute command: '.'`
so I tried escaping the dots as answers for similar questions suggest and the command looks like

```
find . -type f  -path '*/*/dev/composer.json' \
-exec sed -i -e 's/2\.7\.10/dev-supported/7\.x-2\.7\.10/g' {} \;
```

But that fails with `bad flag in substitute command: '\'` error.

Comment: The problem is the extra slashes. `sed` wants `s/.../.../g`. You're giving it `s/.../.../.../g`. Escape the slashes inside the pattern and replacement, or change the delimiter: `s#...#.../...#g`. Nothing to do with dots (except the fact that `7.x-2.7.10` is not a valid flag string).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use slashes in sed replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace)