# sed command to replace string with slashes

Tags: sed, command

I need a `sed` command to replace a line in config file that contains `/`.

I want to change `/var/log/haproxy` to `/root/myDir/haproxy` in the file.

Can you please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry i did not understand what you meant.

Comment: If you just want to replace `/var/log/haproxy` with `/root/myDir/haproxy`, do this: `sed 's@/var/log/haproxy@/root/myDir/haproxy@g'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use slashes in sed replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace a string containing slashes, just use a different delimiter for the `sed` expression:

```
sed 's@/var/log/haproxy@/root/myDir/haproxy@g' <file>
```

Here's an example:

```
$ echo /var/log/haproxy | sed 's@/var/log/haproxy@/root/myDir/haproxy@g'
/root/myDir/haproxy
```

`sed` will automatically use whatever character follows the `s` as the delimiter. These will also work:

```
$ echo /var/log/haproxy | sed 's#/var/log/haproxy#/root/myDir/haproxy#g'
/root/myDir/haproxy
$ echo /var/log/haproxy | sed 's^/var/log/haproxy^/root/myDir/haproxy^g'
/root/myDir/haproxy
$ echo /var/log/haproxy | sed 's%/var/log/haproxy%/root/myDir/haproxy%g'
/root/myDir/haproxy
```

You can also just escape the `/`'s in the path and keep using `/`, but that's harder to read, so I don't recommend it:

```
$ echo /var/log/haproxy | sed 's/\/var\/log\/haproxy/\/root\/myDir\/haproxy/g'
/root/myDir/haproxy
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)