# sed command returns error

Tags: linux, sed, ubuntu-12.04

I was trying to execute this command:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^\$projectroot.*/\$projectroot = \\"\\/home\\/repo\\";/' /etc/gitweb.conf
```

It returned an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 42: unknown option to `s'
```

I don't understand why `s` is used in `sed` command. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use slashes in sed replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command should be:

```
sed -i 's/^\$projectroot.*/\$projectroot = \"\/home\/repo\";/'
```

Sample:

```
$ cat File

aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
$projectroot
dddddddddd

$ sed 's/^\$projectroot.*/\$projectroot = \"\/home\/repo\";/' File

aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
$projectroot = "/home/repo";
dddddddddd
```

Comment: What about `/etc/gitweb.conf`?

Comment: This is a sample.. U can Give '/etc/gitweb.conf' instead of 'File'. See the sample output given