# Insert string under line which contains '/'

Tags: bash, sed

I have file which contains:

```
hello
test1
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
test2
hey
```

Now I try to add the word "`world`" under the line "`DocumentRoot /var/www/html/`"

So that it will look like this:

```
hello
test1
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
world
test2
hey
```

It's difficult for me because the line above contains "`/`"
I tried this but it did not work:

```
sed 's/DocumentRoot /var/#www/#html/#\ /DocumentRoot /var/#www/#html/#\nworld/' file
```

It gave me a totally wrong output

```
hallo
test1
var/var/www/html/
test2
hey
```

Comment: You can use like this : `sed 's@regex@replace@'`

Comment: we should be able to close a question based on SO documentation :P https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/1096/substitution/12280/using-different-delimiters#t=201611030947028728011

Comment: Did you try searching for a solution, this question is asked frequently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the delimiter to a character other than a slash and use the `a` command to append the string:

```
sed '\#DocumentRoot /var/www/html/#a\
world' file
```

Here I'm using the `#` as the delimiter. On some versions of sed you can put all of this onto the same line but the way I've written it is more portable.

Comment: didn't know that different delimiter can be used for matching as well by adding ``\`` at beginning! ++

Comment: @Sundeep I always forget how to do it. This is documented in [Use slashes in sed replace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5864155/1983854). Time to add it into the [Documentation for `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/).

Comment: gnu sed man page - https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-Programs ... see `\%regexp%` under `3.2 Selecting lines with sed`

Comment: @Sundeep no need to go just for GNU. It is better, since also [POSIX defines it](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html#tag_04_126_13_02): _In a context address, the construction "\cBREc", where c is any character other than backslash or <newline>, shall be identical to "/BRE/"._

Comment: Created: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/7720/regular-expression-in-sed