# Using a file's content in sed's replacement string

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I've spent hours searching and can't find a solution to this. I have a directory with over 1,000 PHP files. I need to replace some code in these files as follows:

**Find**:

```
session_register("CurWebsiteID");
```

**Replace with** (saved in replacement.txt:

```
if(!function_exists ("session_register") && isset($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])){require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/libraries/phpruntime/php_legacy_session_functions.php");} session_register("CurWebsiteID");
```

Using the command below, I'm able to replace the pattern with **$(cat replacement.txt)** whereas I'm looking to replace them with the content of the text file.

Command being used:

`find . -name "*.xml" | xargs -n 1 sed -i -e 's/mercy/$(cat replacement.txt)/g'`

I've also tried using variables instead `replacement=code_above;` and running an adjusted version with `$(echo $replacement)` but that doesn't help either.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need command substitution here. You can use the sed `r` command to insert file content and `d` to delete the line matching the pattern:

```
find . -name "*.xml" | xargs -n 1 sed -i -e '/mercy/r replacement.txt' -e '//d'
```

Comment: OMG! That worked beautifully. Thank you very much @SlePort for the elegant solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`$(...)` is not interpreted inside single quotes.  Use double quotes:

```
find . -name "*.xml" | xargs -n 1 sed -i -e "s/mercy/$(cat replacement.txt)/g"
```

You can also do away with `cat`:

```
find . -name "*.xml" | xargs -n 1 sed -i -e "s/mercy/$(< replacement.txt)/g"
```

In case `replacement.txt` has a `/` in it, use a different delimiter in `sed` expression, for example `@`:

```
find . -name "*.xml" | xargs -n 1 sed -i -e "s@mercy@$(< replacement.txt)@g"
```

---

See also:

- [Use slashes in sed replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace)

Comment: I ran: `find . -name "*.xml" | xargs -n 1 sed -i -e "s/mercy/$(< replacement.txt)/g"` and got this error: ***sed: -e expression #1, char 128: unknown option to `s'***

Comment: because your replacement text has `/` chars in it. Try `s@mercy@$(<...)@g` Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I don't understand what I'm supposed to do wth `s@mercy@$(<...)@g`. The pattern I'm after doesn't have `@` in it. What does `@` do?

Comment: Did you try it? Else here's a great `sed` tutorial : http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html . Oh, and depending on your OS, you might need `\s@mercy@...` instead. Good luck.

Comment: And "actually" using `"..."` may cause you other problems, as I see values like `$_SERVER` in your replacement text will be evaluated locally as environment variables. Good luck.

Comment: @codeforester - Your last update showed some improvement. I ran `find . -name "*.xml" | xargs -n 1 sed -i -e "s@mercy@$(< replacement.txt)@g"` and it replaced it with the content of the file, however it replaced `&&` within the file with `mercymercy`, odd. Thanks a lot for the assistance.

Comment: `&` stands for the string that was matched by the pattern after `s/`, which was `mercy`.  So, `&&` would become `mercymercy`.  As @shellter pointed out, special characters like `$` and `&` in replacement.txt can cause problems for your `sed`.