# How can I replace a / with a _ in a shell pipeline?

Tags: bash

Running

```
ip -o -f inet addr show | grep $INTERNAL |awk '/scope global/ {print $4}'
```

Want to replace the `/` in my output to `_` so rather than reading

```
10.168.122.59/16
```

it reads as

```
10.168.122.59_16
```

.

```
|sed s///_/
```

didnt help

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `tr '/' '_'` ...

Comment: Can do it all in awk `ip -o -f inet addr show | awk -vI="$INTERNAL" '$0~I&&/scope global/{sub(/\//,"_",$4);print $4}'`

Comment: That did the trick Thank you

Comment: @123, add that as an answer?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You can if you want, pretty sure this is definitely a duplicate though.

Comment: Hmm. There's definitely a case for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace, though that one assumes `sed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the postprocessing requested can be done internal to `awk`. Expanding a one-liner provided in a [comment by @123](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968192/ip-o-f-inet-addr-show-grep-internal-awk-scope-global-print-4?noredirect=1#comment74966482_43968192) for better readability, this can look like the following:

```
ip -o -f inet addr show | \
  awk -v i="$INTERNAL" '
    $0 ~ i && /scope global/ { 
      sub(/\//, "_", $4);
      print $4;
    }'
```

Breaking down how this works:

- `awk -v i="$INTERNAL"` defines an awk variable based on a shell variable. (As an aside, all-caps shell variable names are bad form; per [POSIX convention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), *lowercase* names are reserved for application use, whereas all-caps names can have meaning to the OS and surrounding tools).
- `$0 ~ i` filters for the entire line (`$0`) matching the awk variable `i`.
- `/scope global/` by default is applied as a regex against `$0` as well (it's equivalent to `$0 ~ /scope global/`).
- `sub(/\//, "_", $4)` substitutes `/`s with `_`s in the fourth field.
- `print $4` prints that field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to scape the `/` or use a different separator as below:

`echo 10.168.122.59/16 | sed s:/:_:`

Comment: If you're going to use `sed`instead of `tr`, at least use `sed y:/:_:`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 10.168.122.59/16| awk '{sub(/\//,"_")}1'
10.168.122.59_16
```