# Sed removal of matching lines and not leave behind blank space

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following text file contents:

> /fubar/bob
>
> /fubar/harry
>
> /fubar/harry-
>
> /fubar/steve
>
> /fubar/tim
>
> /fubar/tim-
>
> /fubar/atim
>
> /fubar/atim-
>
> /fubar/jane

I am using sed to remove all lines containing references to harry, tim and atim.

> sed -i 's#/fubar/\(harry\|tim\|atim\)\(\-\?\)##' /input/testfile.txt

This gives me the following output:

> /fubar/bob
>
> .
>
> .
>
> /fubar/steve
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> /fubar/jane

Where the `.` doesn't actually exist, just using them to represent blank space in the file structure. Is there a way to adjust the sed statement so that it will remove the blank space in one line or will I need a second sed statement to do this? I can't seem to find anything online that combines the blank space removal with another function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use `d` (delete) option in `sed`:

```
sed -E '\#/fubar/(harry|tim|atim)#d' file

/fubar/bob
/fubar/steve
/fubar/jane
```

To save changes back to file use:

```
sed -i.bak -E '\#/fubar/(harry|tim|atim)#d' file
```

Comment: [Here is a working demo](https://ideone.com/j89vka) of above `sed` command.

Comment: Will accept this once I can. Didn't work initially due to user error. Can I ask what the first \ does?

Comment: FIrst backslash is used for escaping an alternative delimiter which is `#` in this case.Otherwise we can use `sed -E '/\/fubar\/(harry|tim|atim)/d' file` also.

Comment: @Mike see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace/5864155#5864155

Answer (score 0):

The more robust **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -F'/' 'NF && $NF!~/(harry|tim|atim)-?/' file > tmp_f && mv tmp_f file
```

The final file contents:

```
/fubar/bob
/fubar/steve
/fubar/jane
```