# Swapping Two Strings using Sed

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file in which I am trying to change two strings or trying to swapping with each other..

```
cat filename| grep m07

filesystem special="/abc/ca97" raw="/abc/ca97" directory="/mount/m07" 
filesystem special="/abc/d1107" raw="/abc/d1107" directory="/m07"
```

so I am trying to swap /mount/m07 with /m07 so that required output should be after operation:

> filesystem special="/abc/ca97" raw="/abc/ca97" directory="/m07"
>   filesystem special="/abc/d1107" raw="/abc/d1107"
>   directory="/mount/m07"

I tried it with using sed..

```
sed -e 's/"\/mount\/m07/"\m07/g' -e 's/"\/m07/"\/mount/\/m07' file_name
```

and

```
sed -e 's/"\/m07/"\/mount/\/m07' -e 's/"\/mount\/m07/"\m07/g' file_name
```

But in both the cases its replacing both the strings so either I get /mount/m07 or /m07 in both of the lines...

could you please suggest the path to reach the desired output...

Answer (score 4):

Simple `sed` will do the task for you.

```
sed '/m07/s#/mount/m07#/m07#;t;/m07/s#/m07#/mount/m07#'    Input_file
```

For Input_file you mentioned or command's output, following will be the output:

```
your_command | sed '/m07/s#/mount/m07#/m07#;n;/m07/s#/m07#/mount/m07#' 
<filesystem special="/abc/ca97" raw="/abc/ca97" directory="/m07" >
<filesystem special="/abc/d1107" raw="/abc/d1107" directory="/m07">
```

**EDIT:** Adding explanation too now for above command, THANKS to Sundeep for letting me know that `t` option is better than `n`. Also following code is only for explanation purposes not for running.

```
sed '/m07/                    Searching for string m07 in a line, if it is present then only do substitutions in that line.
s#/mount/m07#/m07#;           Doing substitution here substitute /mount/m07 with m07 here
t;                            t is for(from man sed page) If  a s/// has done a successful substitution since the last input line was read and since the last t or T command, then branch to label if label is omitted, branch to end of script.
/m07/s#/m07#/mount/m07#       searching string m07 and then substitute string /m07 with /mount/m07
'    Input_file               Mentioning Input_file.
```

Comment: @User123, in `sed` we could create our own separators too eg--> `sed '/m07/s@/mount/m07@/m07@'   Input_file`.

Comment: looks like everybody missed the question - it says swap... so `/mount/m07` is changed to `/m07` and `/m07` is changed to `/mount/m07`

Comment: well, i tried the command you mentioned but it showing /m07 in both lines, whereas I am trying to swap them to get this output..

filesystem special="/abc/ca97" raw="/abc/ca97" directory="/m07"
filesystem special="/abc/d1107" raw="/abc/d1107" directory="/mount/m07"

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 using `n` will work for given example, but not a generic solution.. just add a line in between given sample and you'll see

Comment: @Sundeep, thanks a TON sir for letting know here, changed it in code.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: thanks Ravinder for the explanation.. :)

Answer (score 2):

question is tagged `linux`, so am assuming `GNU sed` is available (not sure if below solution is POSIX). also assuming that both the strings are not present in same line

```
$ sed 's#/mount/m07#/m07#; t; s#/m07#/mount/m07#' ip.txt
filesystem special="/abc/ca97" raw="/abc/ca97" directory="/m07" 
filesystem special="/abc/d1107" raw="/abc/d1107" directory="/mount/m07"
```

- `t` command will branch to specified label on successful substitution
- Without label, `t` will skip rest of commands and start next cycle
- so, if `s#/mount/m07#/m07#` succeeds, `t` command will tell `sed` to skip rest of commands and read next line for processing
- but if the first substitution doesn't succeed, then the second substitution would be attempted

for non-GNU versions - thanks [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)

```
sed -e 's#/mount/m07#/m07#;t' -e 's#/m07#/mount/m07#'
#or
sed -e 's#/mount/m07#/m07#' -e 't' -e 's#/m07#/mount/m07#'
```

**Further Reading**

- [using different delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace)
- [Cleanly swap all occurences of two strings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21061/cleanly-swap-all-occurences-of-two-strings-using-sed)

Comment: ++ Equivalent POSIX `sed` woule be: `sed -e 's#/mount/m07#/m07#;t' -e 's#/m07#/mount/m07#' file`

Comment: @anubhava Why the first `s` and `t` can be together but the second `s` needs to be separated?

Comment: Because POSIX sed attempts to find anything as `label` that comes after `t`. Even a `;` after `t` fails POSIX sed.

Comment: @PesaThe see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Multiple-commands-syntax

Comment: @anubhava Sundeep: I see! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat sedswap.txt 
/mount/m07
/m07

$ sed -e 's/\/mount\/m07/\/rm07/g' -e 's/\/m07/\/mount\/m07/g' -e 's/\/rm07/\/m07/g' sedswap.txt
/m07
/mount/m07
```

Basically using a temp variable approach

Comment: Or like others previously have mentioned use a custom delimiter in sed `$ sed -e 's#/mount/m07#/rm07#g' -e 's#/m07#/mount/m07#g' -e 's#/rm07#/m07#g' sedswap.txt`