# sed on many files - can we do better than invoke-once-per-file?

Tags: bash, sed, command-line, gnu-findutils

I have a set of > 100,000 files to which I want to apply a sed script. Reading the accepted answer to this question:

[Applying sed with multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48445614/1593077)

I see the suggestion involves invoking `sed` for every single one of the files one is interested in, e.g.:

```
find $root_path -type f -name "whatever" -exec sed -i "somecommands" {} \;
```

but while this works - it's a bit silly. After all, sed *is* willing to work on many files, e.g.:

```
sed -i "somecommads" input_file_1 input_file_2
```

So, I would tend to prefer:

```
sed -i "somecommads" $(find $root_path -type f -name "whatever")
```

and this does work.

... except when you have a lot of files. Then, bash tells you "argument list is too long".

Is there an alternative to these two approaches for applying the same sed script to tends, or hundreds, of thousands of files?

Comment: `find .... | xargs sed ...`

Comment: **GNU Parallel** might be a good solution.

Comment: @KamilCuk: Make that an answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
find $root_path -type f -name "whatever" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "somecommads"
```

The `-print0` argument to `find` causes file paths to be printed with a trailing `\0` character rather than a newline, and the corresponding `-0` argument to `xargs` makes it use `\0` as the separator on its input. This will allow for filenames which contain a newline.

Comment: I see no reason not to quote the `$root_path`

Answer (score 4):

You could pipe to `xargs` instead, but most `find` support another flavour of `-exec`, which is run as few times as possible:

```bash
find "$root_path" -type f -name "whatever" -exec sed -i "somecommands" {} +
```

You have to make sure sed still treats the files individually, which is indicated using the `-s`/`--separate` flag – but it's implied by `-i`, so you should be good.