# Use anything as input to sed or Perl regex?

Tags: linux, bash, perl, sed

If I do

```
comment () { sed -i "/$1/s/^/$2 /g" $3 }

comment /dev/sysmsg '#' /tmp/1
comment '*.err'     '#' /tmp/1
```

with input file

```
*.err;kern.notice;auth.notice   /dev/sysmsg
fff
ff
```

then it breaks, as `/` is used in `sed` as separator, and `*` also be treated as a regex.

**Question**

Is there a way to make it robust, so the input string in `$1` can contain whatever I want? Or would I need to move to Perl?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info page has couple of links related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed

Comment: Yes, but it just moves the problem to another char I can't use.

Comment: @hek2mgl No real reason I suppose. Now fixed.

Comment: You can use [`\Q...\E`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) in Perl. If I understand your intentions correctly, try e.g. `function comment { ( perl -i -slpe 's/^(?=\Q$string\E)/$add/' -- -string="$1" -add="$2" $3 ) }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, use bash parameter substitution to escape the troublesome slash character:

```
comment () { sed -i "/${1//\//\\/}/ s/^/${2//\//\\/} /" "$3"; }
```

Notes:

- You need to protect slashes in both the pattern and the replacement parts.
- if your search is anchored, using "g" is pointless because the pattern can match at most once.
- quote all your variables: if the filename contains a space, your code breaks.
- one line functions require a semicolon before the closing brace.

Demo

```
$ cat file
test/1/
test/2/
test/3/

$ comment 'test/2' '//' file

$ cat file
test/1/
// test/2/
test/3/
```

---

I realized I'm not escaping regex special characters. The safest way is to escape any non-alphanumeric characters:

```
comment () { 
    local pattern=$(sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]/\\&/g' <<<"$1")
    local replace=${2//\//\\/}
    local file=$3
    sed -i "/$pattern/ s/^/$replace /" "$file"
}
```

But since you want to do plain text matching, sed is probably not the best tool:

```
comment() { 
    perl -i -pse '$_ = "$leader $_" if index($_, $search) > -1' -- \
        -search="$1" \
        -leader="$2" \
        "$3"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Best to avoid generating code from a shell script.

```
comment () {
   perl -i -pe'BEGIN { ($s,$r)=splice(@ARGV,0,2) }  $_ = "$r $_" if /\Q$s/' -- "$@"
}
```

or

```
comment () {
   s="$1" r="$2" perl -i -pe'$_ = "$ENV{r} $_" if /\Q$ENV{s}/' -- "$3"
}
```

or

```
comment () {
   perl -i -spe'$_ = "$r $_" if /\Q$s/' -- -s="$1" -r="$2" -- "$3"
}
```

Supports:

- Arbitrary text for the search string (including characters that might normally be special in regex patterns, such as `*`). This is achieved by using [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) (as `\Q`) to convert the text into a regex pattern that matches that text.
- Arbitrary file names (including those that contain spaces or start with `-`), thanks to proper quoting and the use of `--`.