# What does "%%" mean in a sed regex?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

In the code base, there is a line:

```
echo x/y/z | sed 's%/[^/]*$%%'
```

It will remove the `/z` from the input string.

I can't quite understand it.

- `s` is substitution
- `%/` is quoting `/`
- `[^/]*$` means matching any characters except `/` any times from the end of line

But what is `%%` here?

Comment: `%` is the delimiter, so substitute `/[^/]*` with nothing. The nothing is `%%` where nothing is between the delimiters. In other forms it is `s/find/replace/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use different delimiters for sed substitute command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/how-to-use-different-delimiters-for-sed-substitute-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's `info sed`:

> The '/' characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single
>   character within any given 's' command.  The '/' character (or whatever
>   other character is used in its stead) can appear in the REGEXP or
>   REPLACEMENT only if it is preceded by a '\' character.

So the `%` is just an arbitrary delimiter. The canonical delimiter is `/`, but that collides with your pattern which is also `/`.

In other words, `%/` isn't an escaped `/`. They're independent characters.

The expression breaks down like this:

```
s              Replace
  %              Delimiter
    /[^/]*$        Search pattern
  %              Delimiter
                   Empty replacement string
  %              Delimiter
```

Which is completely analogous to a simple `s/foo/bar/`:

```
s              Replace
  /              Delimiter
    foo            Search pattern
  /              Delimiter
    bar            Replacement string
  /              Delimiter
```

Comment: It's not completely analogous, as the pattern from the question is anchored at the end of the line, so it'll remove everything from the last occurrence of `/` to the end of the line. A simple substitution would replace the first occurrence.