# How do I use sed to remove a double backslash

Tags: linux, sed, command

I am trying to use sed to remove these double backslashes in the front of this string so that this:

```
//s3.amazonaws.com/umdheader.umd.edu/app/js/main.min.js
```

will become:

```
s3.amazonaws.com/umdheader.umd.edu/app/js/main.min.js
```

so far I have it where it can remove one through the com

```
sed 's/^\///g' output
```

but i need to remove two! please let me know thanks :)

Comment: you just had to add another ``\/`` ... see also: [How to use different delimiters for sed substitute command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/how-to-use-different-delimiters-for-sed-substitute-command)

Comment: @Sash, you could use following solution too by which you need not to escape `/` to remove its special meaning https://stackoverflow.com/a/51139804/5866580

Comment: I don't understand how you could figure out that to remove `/` you use `\/` but couldn't make the leap to using `\/\/` to remove `//`.

Comment: @EdMorton That's funny... a clever person who isn't clever enough to realise why the rest of us aren't as clever ;-) It kind of reminds me of the paradox about whether God is powerful enough to create a boulder that's so big he can't lift it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell IMHO you don't have to be clever to figure out that if X maps to Y then XX **might** map to YY and give it a try! :-)

Comment: Again bulk down voting happened to all answers :(

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I upvoted to restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose another delimiter than `/` in your command:

```
sed 's;^//;;' file
```

Or, if you want to escape the `/`:

```
sed 's/^\/\///' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try it this way with sed:

```
echo  "//s3.amazonaws.com/umdheader.umd.edu/app/js/main.min.js" | sed 's/^.*amazon/amazon/g'
```

or by regular expressions of variables

```
$ variable="//s3.amazonaws.com/umdheader.umd.edu/app/js/main.min.js"
$ echo ${variable#*//}
$ s3.amazonaws.com/umdheader.umd.edu/app/js/main.min.js
```

Answer (score 2):

Or in case you don't want to escape `/` and simple want to substitute `/` starting ones with NULL then do following.

```
echo "//s3.amazonaws.com/umdheader.umd.edu/app/js/main.min.js" | sed 's#^//##'
```