# Sed inside Makefile with extended regex and different delimiter

Tags: variables, sed, makefile, escaping, delimiter

I am using sed inside a makefile with the extended regex to replace the text between defined lines with the variable `Initial` and `Final` like this -

`sed -i -r -e "/$$Initial/,/$$Final/s/$$orig/$$new/g" $$file; \`

The above works, but it has lots of `forward slash` in the values of the variable which works by double escaping those. It would look cleaner if I could replace the delimiter with some other symbols like as follows:

`sed -i -r -e "\!$$Initial!,!$$Final!s!$$orig!$$new!g" $$file ; \`

But this is showing error with `,` in the sed expression. Could you please suggest changes?

Comment: typo? the second regex in address range should be `\!$$Final!`

Comment: Hi @Sundeep! Thank you, I really didn't know that I had to put the second backslash. I could not find this from the documentation. Did you refer documentation?

Comment: the rule is `\cregexpc` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/how-to-use-different-delimiters-for-sed-substitute-command

Comment: The regular expression is defined after `s`. So, in my usage, regex is defined by `$$orig`, and we have not used `\!$$orig!` but `!$$orig!`. Isn't it?

Comment: No, if you want to use a different separator, you have to backslash it. This is so you can say `sed '\!/start/!,\,!/end/!,` to use `!` as the delimiter for the first regex and `,` as the delimiter for the second. These are two separate address expressions which get parsed independently of each other.