# sed: Replace lines matching a pattern that contains forward slashes?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, replace, pattern-matching

I know this question has been asked before, I just can't seem to get the correct syntax for my sed command.

I need to replace `OPP/com.user.opp.orchest.po.services.stub-npo/npo-stub` with `OPP/com.user.opp.orchest.po.services.stub-ica/npo-ica`

A snippet of the file I am replacing it is the following:

**config.xml**

```
<compareType>PLAIN</compareType>
<pattern>
OPP/com.user.opp.orchest.po.services.stub-npo/npo-stub
</pattern>
<branches>
<com.sonyuser.hudson.plugins.gerrit.trigger.hudsontrigger.data.Branch>
<compareType>ANT</compareType>
<pattern>master</pattern>
</com.sonyuser.hudson.plugins.gerrit.trigger.hudsontrigger.data.Branch>
</branches>
${REPO_MIRROR}/OPP/com.user.opp.orchest.po.services.stub-npo/npo-stub
```

I have tried the following,

```
sed -i '/^\/OPP/\com.user.opp.orchest.po.services.stub-npo/\npo-stub\/OPP/\com.user.opp.orchest.po.services.stub-ica/\npo-ica/g' config.xml
```

Comment: Do you want to replace that string only when the line starts with that or anywhere in the file?

Comment: anywhere in the file

Comment: see also: [How to use different delimiters for sed substitute command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your command, you are missing `s` for substitution and have wrongly escaped `\` character. Also as you replied to my comment, that you want to replace it from anywhere in the file, you don't have to use `^` character in your regex. And dot `.` in regex means any character so they need to be escaped too.

You can use this command,

```
sed -i 's/OPP\/com\.user\.opp\.orchest\.po\.services\.stub-npo\/npo-stub/OPP\/com.user.opp.orchest.po.services.stub-ica\/npo-ica/g' yourfilename
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you and @Wiktor Stribiżew for your help and knowledge

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `s` command and replace the `/\` with `\/`. There are some other typos here as well (`\/` at the start is not necessary). Also, escape dots to match literal dots. A good idea is to use some other delimiter here instead of `/`, e.g. `,`, because you have `/` chars in the regex and replacement parts.

You may use

```
sed -i 's,^OPP/com\.user\.opp\.orchest\.po\.services\.stub-npo/npo-stub,OPP/com.user.opp.orchest.po.services.stub-ica/npo-ica,' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/U9gK6n)