# how to find string boot on the /etc/fstab file and replace UUID with kernel device name /dev/sda1?

Tags: sed

how to find string boot on the /etc/fstab file and replace UUID with kernel device name /dev/sda1?

```
cat /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/vg00-root   /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=6fc6605f-796e-4e0b-a8f7-8b339c46b1a9 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg00-tmp    /tmp                    xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg00-var    /var                    xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg00-crash  /var/crash              xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg00-log    /var/log                xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg00-swap   swap                    swap    defaults        0 0

sed 's/UUID/\/dev\/sda1/g' /etc/fstab
```

Comment: So, what does not work? See https://ideone.com/4YqrQm, your code replaces `UUID` with `/dev/sda1`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew probably OP is looking to change UUID only if line contains `boot`... `how to find string boot on the /etc/fstab file and replace UUID`

Comment: Then, maybe `sed '/\/boot/{s,UUID,/dev/sda1,}'  /etc/fstab`, see https://ideone.com/oMmtUb

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/using-different-delimiters-in-sed-commands-and-range-addresses to avoid using `\/`

Comment: sed '/\/boot/{s,UUID[^ ]*,/dev/sda1,}' /etc/fstab

Comment: Aha, so you want to replace the whole `UUID=6fc6605f-796e-4e0b-a8f7-8b339c46b1a9` with a new value. Or not? You accepted an answer that does not check for `/boot`

Comment: @SuhasiniSubramaniam adding complete expected output for given sample would avoid such confusion.. please do so for future questions

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right and below answer helped.

sed '/\/boot/{s,UUID[^ ]*,/dev/sda1,}' /etc/fstab

Comment: What you ask for does not correlate with the accepted solution, hence,  I suggest closing the question as unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that you want to replace `UUID=6fc6605f-796e-4e0b-a8f7-8b339c46b1a9` for `/dev/sda1/`, which is in general a bad idea. The UUID is a unique id belonging to the disk. If you want to replace the disk, I suggest to try to get the UUID with `blkid`.

Otherwise, you should extend the regex in order to replace that part:

```
$ sed 's/UUID=6fc[^ ]*/\/dev\/sda1/g' fstab
```

Note that U've added `6fc` to make sure you will not change every `UUID=` line.

Answer (score 0):

List files under /dev/disk/by-uuid:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

...to obtain something like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 ott  4 18:37 53bc3708-e45d-4352-977a-a62c6a4fd5c8 -> ../../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 ott  4 18:37 6a23dfcf-e36d-45c8-a468-d3976b5239f3 -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 ott  4 18:37 7d6e75e9-7ed2-4412-8acd-2de50ffa0034 -> ../../sda1
```

As you see, you find the old style device name in the right of the output, as link target.

In the uplevel directory, you can find disks categorized by id and by path, not only by uuid. Beautiful!