# Issue with sed and the _ character

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file.txt such as :
that contains:

```
file1
file2
fil3
```

and I would like to print :

```
/beegfs/data/me/these/file1/run_program/file.m8
/beegfs/data/me/these/file2/run_program/file.m8
/beegfs/data/me/these/file3/run_program/file.m8
```

To do so I used :

```
sed 's_.*_"/beegfs/data/me/these/&/run_program/file.m8"' file.txt
```

But it seems that there is something wrong with the `_` character ...

Comment: The command is `s/something/someelse/` - you need trailing closing `_`. Secondly in your command there is a `_` in `run_program` - pick a unique character.

Comment: But I need the _ in the print

Comment: Choose a different separator. Ex `~` is free. `s~something~someelse~`

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace ... also, remove the double quotes if you want expected output as shown in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following could work:

```
sed 's~.*~/beegfs/data/me/these/&/run_program/file.m8~' file.txt
```

Pick `s` command separator that does not exist in replacement string. I see `~` does not exist, so I used it.

The double quotes `"` inside single quotes `'` are interpreted literally. As you don't want them in the output, remove them.