# what is '/[A-Z]/ s| |/|gp' meaning?

Tags: regex, sed

I am reading a sed tutorial at https://riptutorial.com/sed/example/13753/lines-matching-regular-expression-pattern.

Looks like

```
$ sed -n '/[A-Z]/ s| |/|gp' ip.txt
```

is filtering 'Add Sub Mul Div' out of the file, and convert it to 'Add/Sub/Mul/Div'

I really don't understand the regex considering I just read https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x23170.html.

It does not even match the print syntax which is:

```
[address-range]/p
```

and is the pipe sign '|' here alternation?

Could anyone explain:

```
'/[A-Z]/ s| |/|gp'
```

in English?

### Edit

I also found that the extra empty space before 's' and after '/' is allowed and does not do anything. the correct syntax should be:

```
[address-range]/s/pattern1/pattern2/
```

the syntax check of sed pattern is not strict, and confusing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `-n` option turns off automatic printing
- `sed` allows to qualify commands with an address filtering, which could be regex or line addresses

  - for example, `/foo/ d` will delete lines containing `foo`
  - and `/foo/ s/baz/123/` will change `baz` to `123` only if the line also contains `foo`
- `/[A-Z]/` match only lines containing at least one uppercase alphabet

  - if such a line is matched:
  - `s| |/|gp` perform this substitution and print
  - `s` command allows delimiter other than `/` too (see [Using different delimiters in sed commands and range addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/using-different-delimiters-in-sed-commands-and-range-addresses))
  - in this case, using `|` allows you to use `/` as a normal character instead of having to escape it