# sed find and replace variation using ^ instead of /

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I stumbled upon this variation of sed today in my company's codebase.
Essentially we want to swap out `ssh://git@` for `https://` for our CI.

I found this syntax pretty strange and have not been able to find documentation for it on google... Could someone link me to some documentation or provide some insight?

I see it written this way, with `^` separating the search and replace strings. This has removed the need for the `/` separator as well as any escapes. Is this maybe a regex trick?

```
sed 's^ssh://git@^https://^g' -i terraform.tfvars
```

It performs the same as this. Which is what I would have written originally. But the one above just seems so much cleaner and more readable.

```
sed 's/ssh:\/\/git@/https:\/\//g' -i terraform.tfvars
```

Some insight is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command):

> The / characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given s command. The / character (or whatever other character is used in its stead) can appear in the regexp or replacement only if it is preceded by a \ character.

Comment: thanks. actually just saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/using-different-delimiters-in-sed-commands-and-range-addresses
i was searching for the wrong keywords. "delimiter" is what I should have searched for.