# How to tar specific files to specific folder without inside folders path in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I tried to tar specific files for example from: `/home/user/Desktop/source/file.txt` to `/home/user/bin/tar_dir/files.tar` without having folders path in tar file so after unpacking I'd have only files next to `files.tar`.

I found a few questions like that however presented solutions worked for me only if I have specific folder and tar all the files inside this folder. The solutions that worked for files were working only if I am in the folder with the files to tar. I wanted to run the command without going to source folder using command `cd` etc. I'm also using `tar --append` to add files to existing tar file.

I'm new in bash and stuck with this for 2 days and don't have any ideas. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If it's only one file:

```
$ tar cf /tmp/t.tar -C ~/tmp transpose.sh ; tar tf /tmp/t.tar 
transpose.sh
```

So the trick is to go to the target dir with tar -C.

```
$ ls ~/tmp/transpose.sh 
/home/jaroslav/tmp/transpose.sh
```

---

If the files are in different folders:

```
$ tar -cf- ~/tmp/transpose.sh /var/log/Xorg.1.log '--transform=s/.*\///' | tar tf -
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: Removing leading `/' from hard link targets
transpose.sh
Xorg.1.log
```

This uses a sed substitute expression `s///` to replace `.*/` with nothing.

From the GNU tar manual:

> File name transformations
>
> ```
>   --strip-components=NUMBER
>     Strip NUMBER leading components from file names on extraction.
>
>   --transform=EXPRESSION, --xform=EXPRESSION
>     Use sed replace EXPRESSION to transform file names.
> ```

Comment: best by what measure?

Comment: "it's therefore always a good idea not to use a char that is also used literally in regexp" - According to whom? Which authority is this claim based on? Slash is a special character in paths. Did you consider that? Other chars such as , or even : _may_ appear in the filename. / is as good a choice as , and if you claim otherwise, it's based on your opinion or some other preference - such as wanting to avoid escaping the slash in the expression - for whatever reason. Comma is not "best" over slash.

Comment: I'm sure someone will appreciate it.

Comment: ([side note](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864155))