# how to append with sed when pattern is a variable

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to execute the next code:

```
P=$(grep -Ei "^export PATH" "$HOME"/.zshrc)
sed '/'"${P}"'/ a Hello_World' $HOME/.zshrc
```

But i get the next error:

```
sed '/'"${P}"'/ a Hello_World' $HOME/.zshrc
sed: can't find label for jump to `in/DevTools/flutter/bin/:$HOME/bin/DevTools/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/:/usr/local/go/bin/'
```

The objective is append the /usr/local/go/bin, with the existing PATH in the user .*rc (bash,zsh,fish).

other thing is i wanna, make this work with variable, because if the user wanna change the location, will do to the Variable instead of the line.

thanks.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: shell variables does not expand inside single qoutes.

Comment: The problem is that `$P` contains `/` characters and that's ending the `/` that's being used for addressing.

Comment: See related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/using-different-delimiters-in-sed-commands-and-range-addresses

Answer (score 1):

> The objective is append the /usr/local/go/bin, with the existing PATH in the user .*rc (bash,zsh,fish).

Sooo, do exactly that, for example:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin"' >> .zshrc
```

Doing `grep -Ei "^export PATH"` is very much not enough, I could have:

```
: <<COMMENT
export PATH=haha
COMMENT
```

You can't "parse" user customization files, I can put anything in there. Usually, tools just add the stuff on the end file.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, although i had thinking this way, but if the user have this, i don't wanna to touch to much the *rcs files of the user.

Comment: Hello, found the way:
- awk '/^export PATH/ {$0=$0":'${COMPILE_DIR}'/go"} 1' .bashrc > .bashrc # AWK way to append go path to the existing user "export PATH"
- sed "s_^export PATH.*_&:${COMPILE_DIR}/go/bin_" .bashrc # SED way to append go path to the existing user "export PATH"

Answer (score 0):

Found the way:

```
- awk '/^export PATH/ {$0=$0":'${COMPILE_DIR}'/go"} 1' $HOME/.bashrc > .bashrc # AWK way to append go path to the existing user "export PATH"
- sed "s_^export PATH.*_&:${COMPILE_DIR}/go/bin_" $HOME/.bashrc # SED way to append go path to the existing user "export PATH"
```