# bash: ERROR: batch file could not be read

Tags: bash, sed, yt-dlp

Inside `C:\cygwin64\home\Administrator` I have 3 files

```
script.sh
links_da_scaricare.txt
cookies.txt
```

To download from dplay I use successfully if I use this command, videos are downloaded

```
yt-dlp --referer "https:www.discoveryplus.com/" --add-header "Cookie:gcl_au=1.1.192985240.1664694131; _scid=62382352-4832-438c-a74d-30699989ca96; _fbp=fb.1.1664694351012.468612256; __telemetric.v=1599968982.1664694367.81679; __zlcmid=1CFlGmqJqevtvtz; st=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJVU0VSSUQ6ZHBsYXk6MzEzNzY0NDYtOTkwMC00ODVlLWE3YjYtYTkyYzc2MDJkZWE4IiwianRpIjoidG9rZW4tNTA5ZTdiZWYtOTBmMC00ZmVjLWJlNWMtNzJhZmNiZThlYzZmIiwiYW5vbnltb3VzIjpmYWxzZSwiaWF0IjoxNjY0Njk0MzkzfQ.kH5QmwI2CH0-baBgJMGVoalTHbMcwOtH8Go_G2mEz6c; aam_uuid=50034166116354787000738543341305359891; _tt_enable_cookie=1; _ttp=45eb20c2-a55e-4740-be63-01b5e4166bd3; _hjSessionUser_2533509=eyJpZCI6IjM5NDAxNDA3LTllZDQtNWI1ZC1iYjY4LTRiNDlhOWIzMzZhOSIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NjQ2OTQzNjcxNDQsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; AMCV_9AE0F0145936E3790A495CAA@AdobeOrg=-1124106680|MCIDTS|19268|MCMID|50189272745869278580790010530934545485|MCAAMLH-1665300361|6|MCAAMB-1665300361|RKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y|MCOPTOUT-1664702762s|NONE|MCSYNCSOP|411-19275|vVersion|5.2.0; __telemetric.s=1.1664980917.1664982717; _hjSession_2533509=eyJpZCI6ImVhNmZmNTA3LTM1ZGYtNDBlZC1iMWFjLTA0MzRlYzZlYjJjNCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NjQ5ODA5MTc5MTEsImluU2FtcGxlIjpmYWxzZX0=; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; _clck=ji7lnf|1|f5g|0; fs_uid=#161CV1#6518423911501824:5976792460267520:::#/1696517470; _uetsid=2596f2d044bd11ed80c355f240f55627; _uetvid=c8269d50422011ed952c2140169cc91d; ABTastySession=mrasn=&sen=9&lp=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.discoveryplus.com%2Fit; ABTasty=uid=4hnc3e5beewkxmkz&fst=1664694364438&pst=1664813235740&cst=1664981468233&ns=4&pvt=21&pvis=10&th=; _clsk=6lrbo9|1664981584916|8|0|j.clarity.ms/collect" --batch-file links_da_scaricare.txt
```

ok, I try to download using Cygwin and I use this command

```
bash -x script.sh
```

But I get this error

```
$ bash -x script.sh
+ IFS=
+ read -r url
++ echo https://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-1-strada-per-linferno
++ sed 'shttps://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/\(.*\)/.*~\1'
sed: -e expression #1, char 52: unterminated `s' command
+ folder_name=
+ echo 'folder_name: '
folder_name:
+ mkdir -p /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator/
+ echo 'The script is running and creating folder: '
+ yt-dlp --referer https://www.discoveryplus.com/ --cookies /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator/cookies.txt -a https://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-1-strada-per-linferno -o '/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator//%(title)s.%(ext)s'
ERROR: batch file https://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-1-strada-per-linferno could not be read
+ IFS=
+ read -r url
++ echo https://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-2-non-in-kansas
++ sed 'shttps://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/\(.*\)/.*~\1'
sed: -e expression #1, char 52: unterminated `s' command
+ folder_name=
+ echo 'folder_name: '
folder_name:
+ mkdir -p /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator/
+ echo 'The script is running and creating folder: '
+ yt-dlp --referer https://www.discoveryplus.com/ --cookies /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator/cookies.txt -a https://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-2-non-in-kansas -o '/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator//%(title)s.%(ext)s'
ERROR: batch file https://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-2-non-in-kansas could not be read
+ IFS=
+ read -r url
```

`script.sh` have this code

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r url; do
folder_name=$(echo "$url" | sed 'shttps://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/\(.*\)/.*~\1')

    echo "folder_name: $folder_name"
    mkdir -p "/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator/$folder_name"
    echo "The script is running and creating folder: $folder_name" > ~/script.log
        yt-dlp --referer "https://www.discoveryplus.com/" --cookies "/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator/cookies.txt" -a "$url" -o "/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator/$folder_name/%(title)s.%(ext)s"
    done < /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator/links_da_scaricare.txt
```

`links_da_scaricare.txt` have these 3 lines - I use notepad to copy paste these links

```
https://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-1-strada-per-linferno
https://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-2-non-in-kansas
https://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/il-boss-delle-cerimonie/stagione-5-il-quarantesimo-compleanno-di-nello
```

`cookies.txt` is this - is the same that I use in powershell command so it should download because with powershell I can do it but with bash i have problems, I don't know why

```
gcl_au=1.1.192985240.1664694131; _scid=62382352-4832-438c-a74d-30699989ca96; _fbp=fb.1.1664694351012.468612256; __telemetric.v=1599968982.1664694367.81679; __zlcmid=1CFlGmqJqevtvtz; st=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJVU0VSSUQ6ZHBsYXk6MzEzNzY0NDYtOTkwMC00ODVlLWE3YjYtYTkyYzc2MDJkZWE4IiwianRpIjoidG9rZW4tNTA5ZTdiZWYtOTBmMC00ZmVjLWJlNWMtNzJhZmNiZThlYzZmIiwiYW5vbnltb3VzIjpmYWxzZSwiaWF0IjoxNjY0Njk0MzkzfQ.kH5QmwI2CH0-baBgJMGVoalTHbMcwOtH8Go_G2mEz6c; aam_uuid=50034166116354787000738543341305359891; _tt_enable_cookie=1; _ttp=45eb20c2-a55e-4740-be63-01b5e4166bd3; _hjSessionUser_2533509=eyJpZCI6IjM5NDAxNDA3LTllZDQtNWI1ZC1iYjY4LTRiNDlhOWIzMzZhOSIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NjQ2OTQzNjcxNDQsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; AMCV_9AE0F0145936E3790A495CAA@AdobeOrg=-1124106680|MCIDTS|19268|MCMID|50189272745869278580790010530934545485|MCAAMLH-1665300361|6|MCAAMB-1665300361|RKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y|MCOPTOUT-1664702762s|NONE|MCSYNCSOP|411-19275|vVersion|5.2.0; __telemetric.s=1.1664980917.1664982717; _hjSession_2533509=eyJpZCI6ImVhNmZmNTA3LTM1ZGYtNDBlZC1iMWFjLTA0MzRlYzZlYjJjNCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NjQ5ODA5MTc5MTEsImluU2FtcGxlIjpmYWxzZX0=; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; _clck=ji7lnf|1|f5g|0; fs_uid=#161CV1#6518423911501824:5976792460267520:::#/1696517470; _uetsid=2596f2d044bd11ed80c355f240f55627; _uetvid=c8269d50422011ed952c2140169cc91d; ABTastySession=mrasn=&sen=9&lp=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.discoveryplus.com%2Fit; ABTasty=uid=4hnc3e5beewkxmkz&fst=1664694364438&pst=1664813235740&cst=1664981468233&ns=4&pvt=21&pvis=10&th=; _clsk=6lrbo9|1664981584916|8|0|j.clarity.ms/collect
```

In other words script.sh should be do this

--> read urls from `links_da_scaricare.txt` and extract only these strings

```
citta-mortale
il-boss-delle-cerimonie
```

--> make folders with that names

--> download

```
https://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-1-strada-per-linferno
https://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-2-non-in-kansas
```

in this folder

```
citta-mortale
```

--> download

```
https://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/il-boss-delle-cerimonie/stagione-5-il-quarantesimo-compleanno-di-nello
```

--> in this folder

```
il-boss-delle-cerimonie
```

Script creates the first folder but doesn't download anything inside it

Comment: The sed expression is indeed buggy, just as the error message tells you. You need to have a sigil character after `s` before the thing to be replaced, then repeat that sigil between the regex to be replaced and the content to replace it with, and again at the end of the replacement content.

Comment: See [Using different delimiters in sed commands and range addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/using-different-delimiters-in-sed-commands-and-range-addresses) -- granted, the problem your code has most immediately is that it isn't using any delimiter _at all_ (so you end up with a delimiter of `h`, even though that's clearly intended to be the first character of the search string). Maybe you meant to use a `~` as the delimiter but left it out in the first position?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to download files into a directory named according to the **6th field** delimited by "**/**" in the **url** specification (*between slash #5 and #6*).

That is accomplished as

**folder_name=$( echo "${url}" | cut -f6 -d/ )**

Regarding sed, you must specify a delimiter character which does not conflict with any possible characters that might be found in the text string that you are trying to edit.

For URLs that always have "/", you cannot use "/" as that delimiter.  You must choose something else.  I tend to use either the "+" or the "|" depending on circumstances.

So to strip the prefix from the URL string, you would use

```
echo "${url}" | sed 's+https://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/++'
```

to obtain

```
citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-1-strada-per-linferno
citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-2-non-in-kansas
il-boss-delle-cerimonie/stagione-5-il-quarantesimo-compleanno-di-nello
```

You would make a second, similar, usage of sed to strip the tail end after the "/".

OR ... you can again use cut in this manner

**id_string=$( echo "${url}" | cut -f7 -d/ )**

to obtain

```
stagione-1-episodio-1-strada-per-linferno
stagione-1-episodio-2-non-in-kansas
stagione-5-il-quarantesimo-compleanno-di-nello
```

Comment: `#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r url; do
    folder_name=$( echo "${url}" | cut -f6 -d/ )
 echo "${url}" | sed 's+https://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/++'
    mkdir -p "/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator/$folder_name"
 
    echo "The script is running and creating folder: $folder_name" > ~/script.log
    yt-dlp --referer "https://www.discoveryplus.com/" --cookies "/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator/cookies.txt" -a "$url" -o "/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator/$folder_name/%(title)s.%(ext)s"
done < /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator/links_da_scaricare.txt`

Comment: I edit script.sh  in that way but cygwin terminal returns me this error `Administrator@pip ~
$ bash -x script.sh
+ IFS=
+ read -r url
++ echo citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-1-strada-per-linferno
++ cut -f6 -d/
+ folder_name=
+ echo citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-1-strada-per-linferno
+ sed s+https://www.discoveryplus.com/it/video/++
citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-1-strada-per-linferno
+ mkdir -p /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator/
+ echo 'The script is running and creating folder: '
+ yt-dlp --referer https://www.discoveryplus.com/ --cookies`

Comment: `/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator/cookies.txt -a citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-1-strada-per-linferno -o '/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/Administrator//%(title)s.%(ext)s'
ERROR: batch file citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-1-strada-per-linferno could not be read`

Comment: I don't understand why always it give me "ERROR: batch file citta-mortale/stagione-1-episodio-1-strada-per-linferno could not be read"

Comment: Step away from the code.

If you start by writing the code logic 

 - *in pseudo-code*, 
 - fine-grained for each task that you are trying to accomplish, 
 - in the correct sequence and 
 - in the correct context, 

then having that worded so that it does exactly what you want it to do ... will, *almost explicitly*, tell you **WHAT** you need to code for each of those, not the **HOW**. The **HOW** is the nitty gritty of coding.  The solution should then be obvious.

What you have provided above in your question does not reflect that level of thought on the task breakdown.