# sed delete line with file path

Tags: sed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sed: delete using a different delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797906/sed-delete-using-a-different-delimiter)

I can substitute line in file like this

```
sed "s|$PATH_WITH_SLASH||" file
```

but I cannot delete it

```
sed "|$PATH_WITH_SLASH|d"  file
```

The problem is that **|** character cannot be used for deletion. Why?

Comment: This question has already been answered at least once before. This should explain things clearly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797906/sed-delete-using-a-different-delimiter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use other character as address delimiter, you need to use backslash before the first char. So

```
/address/
```

or

```
\|address|
```