# Replace the string content in sed with special chars

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have the code like this:

```
sed "s/TEST_CASES_R/$testCaseLocations/g" template >> newfile
```

where `$testCaseLocations` has `,tests/test/,tests/test/2`. So this line is failing like:

> bad flag in substitute command

How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed: delete using a different delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797906/sed-delete-using-a-different-delimiter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, sed code injection. What sed sees is

```
sed "s/TEST_CASES_R/,tests/test/,tests/test/2/g" template >> newfile
```

...which is nonsensical. The root problem is that sed cannot differentiate between the things you want it to see as data -- the contents of `$testCaseLocations` -- and instructions.

The best solution in my opinion is to use awk:

```
awk -v replacement="$testCaseLocations" '{ gsub(/TEST_CASES_R/, replacement); print }' template >> newfile
```

because this neatly sidesteps code injection problems by not treating `testCaseLocations` as code. You could, in this particular case, also use a different delimiter for sed, such as

```
 sed "s@TEST_CASES_R@$testCaseLocations@g" template >> newfile
```

but then you'd run into trouble if `$testCaseLocations` contains a `@`, or if it contains a character that has meaning for sed in the context where it appears, such as `\` or `&`.

Comment: Thanks for awk solution. Neat one.

Comment: Gsub defaults to $0 so the last arg is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just use another separator for `sed`, otherwise it sees so many slashes around: `sed 's#hello#bye#g'` is fine.

In your case:

```
sed "s#TEST_CASES_R#$testCaseLocations#g" template >> newfile
```

See another test:

```
$ var="/hello"
$ echo "test" | sed "s/test/$var/g"
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'
$ echo "test" | sed "s#test#$var#g"
/hello
```