# Bash: Parse Urls from file, process them and then remove them from the file

Tags: bash, parsing, sed, xargs

I am trying to automate a procedure where the system will fetch the contents of a file (1 Url per line), use wget to grab the files from the site (https folder) and then remove the line from the file.

I have made several tries but the sed part (at the end) cannot understand the string (I tried escaping characters) and remove it from that file!

```
cat File
https://something.net/xxx/data/Folder1/
https://something.net/xxx/data/Folder2/
https://something.net/xxx/data/Folder3/
```

My line of code is:

```
cat File | xargs -n1 -I @ bash -c 'wget -r -nd -l 1 -c -A rar,zip,7z,txt,jpg,iso,sfv,md5,pdf --no-parent --restrict-file-names=nocontrol --user=test --password=pass --no-check-certificate "@" -P /mnt/USB/ && sed -e 's|@||g' File'
```

It works up until the `sed -e 's|@||g' File` part..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're going to read the whole file, why remove its content line by line? couldn't you just `data=$(cat File); echo -n > File` ?

Comment: For more advanced cases you might want to consider using `flock`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@beliy answers looks good!

If you want a one-liner, you can do:

```
while read -r line; do \
wget -r -nd -l 1 -c -A rar,zip,7z,txt,jpg,iso,sfv,md5,pdf \
--no-parent --restrict-file-names=nocontrol --user=test \
--password=pass --no-check-certificate "$line" -P /mnt/USB/ \
&& sed -i -e '\|'"$line"'|d' "File.txt"; \
done < File.txt
```

EDIT:
[You need to add a `\` in front of the first pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797906/delete-using-a-different-delimiter)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
After the do it required an extra space.. I run it and while it tries to download the test locations I added (3 false and 1 good) when it reaches the sed part I get:
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `|'

Comment: Good point, you need a `\` in front of the first `|` apparently, I didn't know that! Thanks!

Comment: Correct and if you change `sed -e with sed -i` it is exactly what I was searching for ;)

Answer (score 2):

Dont use cat if it's posible. It's bad practice and can be problem with big files... You can change

```
cat File | xargs -n1 -I @ bash -c
```

to

```
for siteUrl in $( < "File" ); do
```

It's be more correct and be simpler to use sed with double quotes... My variant:

```
scriptDir=$( dirname -- "$0" )
for siteUrl in $( < "$scriptDir/File.txt" )
do
    if [[ -z "$siteUrl" ]]; then break; fi # break line if him empty
    wget -r -nd -l 1 -c -A rar,zip,7z,txt,jpg,iso,sfv,md5,pdf --no-parent --restrict-file-names=nocontrol --user=test --password=pass --no-check-certificate "$siteUrl" -P /mnt/USB/ && sed -i "s|$siteUrl||g" "$scriptDir/File.txt"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
How can I get it to update the File itself?
I test it with 4 lines (3 not valid and 1 valid). I get on the screen the desired output (4 lines with a gap between them, the valid is missing) but the file remains unchanged..

Comment: I have tried switching to `sed -i "|$siteUrl|d"` but I get `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `|'`.

Comment: there is also another issue, when the URL contains spaces this code brakes it down as different elements..

Comment: sorry, i dont test code and fast change u line. For update file need use `-i` for sed. Use `sed -i "s|$siteUrl||g"` or `sed -i "\|$siteUrl|d"`
Are you can give me 1 problem URL for test?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to use double quotes after `sed -e`. Instead of:

```
'...&& sed -e 's|@||g' File'
```

you would need

```
'...&& sed -e '"'s|@||g'"' File'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
The double quotes works (it used to through an error).

Comment: I am trying to change it to `sed -i '"'|@|d'"'` but cannot get it to work.. Do you have an idea??

Answer (score 0):

I see what you trying to do, but I dont understand the `sed` command including pipes. Maybe some fancy format that I dont understand.

Anyway, I think the sed command should look like this...

```
sed -e 's/@//g'
```

This command will remove all @ from the stream.
I hope this helps!